# Estou criando um modal para trazer informações de uma API

Tags: javascript, react

Estou criando um modal em ReactJS com material UI mas estou com dificuldades de fazer ele funcionar. Sou novo em React e esse código é mais para meu treinamento pessoal. O erro que fica dando é:

> setOpen is not a function

E estou travado nele.

```
import React,{ Component } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';
import Backdrop from '@material-ui/core/Backdrop';
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade';
import "./App.css";

class Mod extends Component{   
    state = {
        rows:[]
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) =>{
            this.setState({rows: response.results});
        })
        
    }    
   
    useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        modal: {
          display: 'flex',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        },
        paper: {
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
          border: '2px solid #000',
          boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
          padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
        },
      }));
      render() {
          const classes = this.useStyles;
          const {open,setOpen} = false;
          const rows = this.state;
          
          
          const handleOpen=()=> {
              setOpen(true);
          };
          const  handleClose=()=>{
              this.setOpen(false);
          }

        return (
            <div>
                <button type="button" onClick={handleOpen}>
                    react-transition-group
                </button>
                <Modal
                    aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
                    aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
                    className={classes.modal}
                    open={open}
                    onClose={handleClose}
                    closeAfterTransition
                    BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
                    BackdropProps={{
                    timeout: 500,
                    }}
                >
                    <Fade in={open}>
                    <div className={classes.paper}>
                        <h2 id="transition-modal-title">Transition modal</h2>
                        <p id="transition-modal-description">react-transition-group animates me.</p>
                    </div>
                    </Fade>
                </Modal>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
export default Mod;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oi, você está tentando usar un `hook`, so pode usar `hook` com componentes funcionais

```
const [open,setOpen] = useState(false);
```

Neste caso tem que usar a velha metodología [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

```
// mudar modelo do estado
state = {
        rows:[],
        isOpen: false,
    }
// atualizar estado
this.setState({isOpen: true});
```